# How to get Ascii Text Art Formatted Properly For Excel MsgBox

Tags: excel, vba, text, format

A belated happy April 1st friends. Like most of you, I have always felt Excel lacked a Skull and Bones graphical image as part of the `vba` `MsgBox` routine. Frankly the red `vbCritical` just doesn't go far enough to alarm users when they've really done something horrible.

So I thought, *enough is enough*, I need a SKULL! Many of my customers have a standard of professionalism that prevents me from making custom FORMS. Thus, not wanting to violate any codes of conduct, I considered graphical text options of ASCII SKULLS. A quick [DuckDuck](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Skull+Art+Text+ASCII&t=h_&ia=web) search [brought me some of the finest skull compilation art](http://ascii.co.uk/art/skulls) on the web.

At this point, I figured I was going to be in business but as you can see below, the `MsgBox` version of my [favorite masterpiece](https://pastebin.com/raw/nbnGLnNR) leaves much to be desired! Clearly, this won't alarm anyone...

I suspect the issue is the method I'm using to store the art (as `Comment.Text`) is formatting in some undesirable way. Is there a way to control this, or is there a better method to store text in Excel to preserve the text art format?

My vba code is basic: `MsgBox Range("A1").Comment.Text`

[image: Not Scary Enough!]

Also.... it works great on SO!

```
                 uuuuuuu
             uu$$$$$$$$$$$uu
          uu$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$uu
         u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
        u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
       u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
       u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u
       u$$$$$$"   "$$$"   "$$$$$$u
       "$$$$"      u$u       $$$$"
        $$$u       u$u       u$$$
        $$$u      u$$$u      u$$$
         "$$$$uu$$$   $$$uu$$$$"
          "$$$$$$$"   "$$$$$$$"
            u$$$$$$$u$$$$$$$u
             u$"$"$"$"$"$"$u
  uuu        $$u$ $ $ $ $u$$       uuu
 u$$$$        $$$$$u$u$u$$$       u$$$$
  $$$$$uu      "$$$$$$$$$"     uu$$$$$$
u$$$$$$$$$$$uu    """""    uuuu$$$$$$$$$$
$$$$"""$$$$$$$$$$uuu   uu$$$$$$$$$"""$$$"
 """      ""$$$$$$$$$$$uu ""$"""
           uuuu ""$$$$$$$$$$uuu
  u$$$uuu$$$$$$$$$uu ""$$$$$$$$$$$uuu$$$
  $$$$$$$$$$""""           ""$$$$$$$$$$$"
   "$$$$$"                      ""$$$$""
     $$$"                         $$$$"
```

Comment: ASCII art often relies on a mono-spaced (non-proportional) font, which is not what Msgbox uses...

Comment: @SiddharthRout to be clear, I'm copying to the NOTE or yellow tab in the cell, which seems more text friendly than the cell.

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. I wasn't familiar with the term "Mono-spaced" but I suspect that may be the issue. I'll do some searches using that term and see if I find anything.

Comment: What you want from Msgbox (to change the default font) is not straightforward - https://www.google.com/search?q=vba+change+msgbox+font+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: Thanks @TimWilliams. I know the best solution is just to use a form, but I was hoping there might be a way to drop it into the standard msgbox. It does look like the comment note is messing with the spacing FIRST, but even if I play around with basic text lines in VBA, it seems to scew them... If you want to post this as an answer, I'll accept it in a day or two unless someone finds something that works.

Comment: Storing text in a comment doesn't affect the content - if you switch the comment font to (eg) Courier it will look "correct"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in comments: ASCII art often relies on a mono-spaced (non-proportional) font, which is not what the out-of-the-box `Msgbox` uses. So it's very difficult, if not impossible to do strictly with `MsgBox` tool.

However, create your own `MsgBox` instead and call it whenever needed. Using `Courier` as the font for `Label1` (Courier IS mono-spaced).

[image]

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim DispStr() As String

    ReDim DispStr(1 To 26)

DispStr(1) = "                 uuuuuuu"
DispStr(2) = "             uu$$$$$$$$$$$uu"
DispStr(3) = "          uu$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$uu"
DispStr(4) = "         u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u"
DispStr(5) = "        u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u"
DispStr(6) = "       u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u"
DispStr(7) = "       u$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$$u"
DispStr(8) = "       u$$$$$$""   ""$$$""   ""$$$$$$u"
DispStr(9) = "       ""$$$$""      u$u       $$$$"""
DispStr(10) = "        $$$u       u$u       u$$$"
DispStr(11) = "        $$$u      u$$$u      u$$$"
DispStr(12) = "         ""$$$$uu$$$   $$$uu$$$$"""
DispStr(13) = "          ""$$$$$$$""   ""$$$$$$$"""
DispStr(14) = "            u$$$$$$$u$$$$$$$u"
DispStr(15) = "             u$""$""$""$""$""$""$u"
DispStr(16) = "  uuu        $$u$ $ $ $ $u$$       uuu"
DispStr(17) = " u$$$$        $$$$$u$u$u$$$       u$$$$"
DispStr(18) = "  $$$$$uu      ""$$$$$$$$$""     uu$$$$$$"
DispStr(19) = "u$$$$$$$$$$$uu    """"""""""    uuuu$$$$$$$$$$"
DispStr(20) = "$$$$""""""$$$$$$$$$$uuu   uu$$$$$$$$$""""""$$$"""
DispStr(21) = """""""      """"$$$$$$$$$$$uu """"$"""""""
DispStr(22) = "           uuuu """"$$$$$$$$$$uuu"
DispStr(23) = "  u$$$uuu$$$$$$$$$uu """"$$$$$$$$$$$uuu$$$"
DispStr(24) = "  $$$$$$$$$$""""""""           """"$$$$$$$$$$$"""
DispStr(25) = "   ""$$$$$""                      """"$$$$"""""
DispStr(26) = "     $$$""                         $$$$"""

Me.Label1.Caption = Join(DispStr, vbNewLine)
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

[image]

You can obviously play around with the formatting yourself to get the end result that you want